# What is the bug in this Java programm?

Tags: catch-block

The compiler is not executing the `catch` part when no value is entered:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class Ruff {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String a;

        Scanner scanf=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your name!!");
        a=scanf.nextLine();

        try
        {
            if(a.toLowerCase().equals("Harsh"))
            {
                System.out.print("Good Name");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Ok!");
            }  
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("Name Required");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not answering your question, but I think it should be `a.toLowerCase().equals("harsh")`

Comment: Please when asking questions be sure to spend some effort in explaining clearly and properly formatting them. Also, you may want to tag your question with the relevant language used (java, in your case). Back to your question, there is nothing in your try block which raises exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible exception for `a` in the code is a `NullpointerException`, but `a` is the empty string not a null pointer If the user enters no value. You should check for that value instead of using exceptions:

```
if(a.equals("")) {
    System.out.print("Name Required");
}
else {
    // code of try block here ...
}
```